# WPF Bing Maps pushpin consistently landing away from the mouse position

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to drop a file on the map which will then place a pin with a path attached to the pin (so I can click the pin and go to the path in windows explorer).

However the pin seems to drop under the `Grid.Column(0)` map icon which was also [mentioned here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/33aee9e7-6392-4186-89e0-664df0798246/getting-wrong-location-details-on-mouse-click-in-wpf?forum=bingmapssilverlightwpfcontrols) although there is no further discussion.

If the app is on a different display, then the pin seems to drop just outside the view to the right.

Another thing I noticed was that no matter where I drop the file, the coordinates seem to be the same unless I give the window a wriggle between trying.

Assuming the issue comes from the grid.column, how could i account for this?

Something like: `pt.x += worldMap.width/2`

Here is my window:
[image: Window Layout]

This is my fileDidDrop function:

```
        private void File_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            {
                string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

                // File dir
                Console.WriteLine(files[0].ToString());

                // Get mouse coords
                Point pt = Mouse.GetPosition(worldMap);

                Location dropLoc = worldMap.ViewportPointToLocation(pt);

                new Location(pt.X,pt.Y);

                GeoPushpin newPin = new GeoPushpin();
                newPin.Location = dropLoc;
                worldMap.Children.Add(newPin);
            }
        }
```

And this is the XAML for my `worldMap`

```
            <m:Map x:Name="worldMap" 
                   CredentialsProvider="MY_KEY" 
                   Mode="Road"  
                   Grid.Column="1" 
                   ZoomLevel="4" 
                   Center="-27.608,134.8099"
                   Drop="File_Drop" 
                   AllowDrop="True">
            </m:Map>
```

Ta.

Answer (score 0):

I guess as they mentioned in the link it may be issue of custom push pins, You can try with controls which inherits from map only like map polygons and you can draw push pin with in it.

Comment: Could you explain a bit further please Vadi, I'm relatively new to wpf. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I came up with. I noticed that the pin would always offset toward the origin of my extended displays.

This means we could adjust the pt by the mouse position relative to the screen and problem solved.

```
private void File_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

            // File dir
            Console.WriteLine(files[0].ToString());

            // Get mouse coords
            Point mouse = PointToScreen(e.GetPosition(this));
            Point pt = Mouse.GetPosition(worldMap);

            Point adjustedPt = new Point();
            adjustedPt.X = pt.X + mouse.X;
            adjustedPt.Y = pt.Y + mouse.Y;

            Location dropLoc = worldMap.ViewportPointToLocation(adjustedPt);

            GeoPushpin newPin = new GeoPushpin();
            newPin.Location = dropLoc;
            worldMap.Children.Add(newPin);
        }
    }
```